# Replacement of file using perl

Tags: perl

Using the below code, I want to replace html tag "`<div class="blank">\n<p>`" with "`<table>\n<tr>`". But we can't replace `<div class="blank">` with `<table>` and `<p>` with `<tr>`, Because there is more occurrence in different format.

```
use warnings ;
use strict;
my $directory = <STDIN>;
chomp($directory); #Remove the last enter from the key board
    foreach my $fp (glob("$directory/*.html"))
        {
            open (read_file, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $fp)  or die "Could not open file '$fp' $!";
            my @fh = <read_file>;
            close(read_file);
            my @o_filename = split '\/' , $fp;
            my $f_name_split = $o_filename[-1];
            my @f_nmae = split '\.' , $f_name_split;
            unlink ($fp);
            my @newlines;
            foreach(@fh)
                {   
                    $_ =~ s/<div class="blank">\n<p>/<table>\n<p>/;
                    push(@newlines, $_);
                }
                open(write_file, ">$directory\/$f_nmae[0].htm") || die "File not found";
                print write_file @newlines;
                close(write_file);
        }
        print ("\n\t----------------Done----------------\n");
```

***Input :-***

```
<div class="blank">
<p>songs</p>
```

***Output :-***

```
<table>
<tr>songs</p>
```

Comment: Can you add sample input?

Comment: Input:-
<div class="blank">
<p>songs</p>

Output:-

<table>
<tr>songs</p>


Note:- Renaming correction i will do on my hand about </p> replace with </tr>.

Comment: So you want replace only beginning `<p>` with `<tr>`?

Comment: Can you please edit you question with input and expected output?

Comment: Please see again for input and output

sorry i confused you

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$_ =~ s/<div class="blank">\n<p>/<table>\n<p>/;
```

to:

```
s/<div class="blank">/<table>/;
s/<p>songs<\/p>/<tr>songs<\/p>/;
```

Otherside there is no need of a new array. This piece of code:

```
my @newlines;
foreach(@fh)
{   
    $_ =~ s/<div class="blank">\n<p>/<table>\n<p>/;
    push(@newlines, $_);
}
open(write_file, ">$directory\/$f_nmae[0].htm") || die "File not found";
print write_file @newlines;
close(write_file);
```

can be written as:

```
foreach(@fh)
{   
    s/<div class="blank">/<table>/;
    s/<p>songs<\/p>/<tr>songs<\/p>/;
}
open $write_file, ">$directory\/$f_nmae[0].htm" or die "File not found: $!";
print $write_file @fh;
close $write_file;
```

You can modify `@fh` itself. And always use lexical filehandle.

Comment: i don't want escape \n. 

Actually the input is :-

<div class="blank">
<p>songs</p>


and i want output:-

<table>
<tr>songs</p>


i was also try with your code but still same problem

Comment: No we can not changed as you write because there is more instance in file.                      s/<div class="blank">/<table>/;
s/<p>songs<\/p>/<tr>songs<\/p>/;

Comment: What you mean by _there is more instance in file_? If you are not going to show us your input file, we can't assume what exactly you want to do. What input you have given for that above code will work.